# civicrm print invoice button

Tags: printing, invoice, civicrm

In civicrm print invoice button is not working in wordpress. Error occur like this

```
        Firefox can't find the file at http://wwwwwwwwww/dashboard/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/contribute/invoice&reset=1&id=43&cid=2.
```

how to resolve this ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a real answer for this - but my working local drupal url looks like:

```
http://dmaster.local/civicrm/contribute/invoice?reset=1&id=185&cid=202
```

Whereas yours is:

```
http://wwwwwwwwww/dashboard/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/contribute/invoice&reset=1&id=43&cid=2
```

My guess is that you are accessing it from the contact dashboard & some wordpressness is prepended to the url. If you take the last part & swap it into a working wordpress url does it work?

If you can replicate the bug on the sandbox (http://wp46.demo.civicrm.org/) then you should log a JIRA issue.