# Print PDF when contributions status is completed

Tags: wordpress, pdf, civicrm

Can anyone say, how to print the PDF in when contributions status is completed? I don't know how to regenerate the code in civicrm using WordPress?

Please tell me how to regenerate it?

Comment: Can you clarify how the original PDF is being generated?

Comment: In dashboard only pdf in generating. If the contributions is pending , the print invoice button appearing, i just want when the contribution is completed , the print invoice button should appear or else it won't

Comment: john - if you go to this Contact Dashboard http://d46.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/user?reset=1 when logged in, i see that user 'asd asd' has Print Invoice buttons for two 'completed' contributions. Is this what you are describing? And are you saying that in your situation you do not have these buttons when the Contribution is Completed? I don't think your question has been very easy to help since you have provided so little information. Some links, examples and screenshots take a lot of the guesswork out of this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31779557/civicrm-print-invoice-button

Comment: click the above link and tel me what mistake i have done?

Comment: no idea but that path with 'wwwwwwwwww' in it looks v suspicious - can you checking your settings